# Knuth down-arrow notation

Tags: logarithms, tetration

I was reading this article on MathWorld: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DownArrowNotation.html,

and I decided to check the statement

> $\ln^{*}n$ is the number of times the natural logarithm must be
> iterated to obtain a value $\leq e$.

But shouldn't it be $\leq 1$ ? I tried a simple check with the 3rd tetration of $e$. For
$e \downarrow \downarrow e^{e^e} = \ln^{*}e^{e^e}$:

Try $\space \ln e^{e^e} = e^e \ln e \space \neq e$.

Try $\space \ln\ln e^{e^e} = e \ln (e\ln e) = e$.

This is, however, only 2 iterations. Could anyone help me find the problem?

Comment: It is possible they meant $<e$ rather than $\leq e$.

Comment: $n$ is slightly suggestive that this supposed to be an integer.  $\log^*$ is the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).  Presumably the aim is to find something like an opposite of the up-arrow notation, though I doubt this works satisfactorily however you define it

Comment: @Henry No need to presume. If you follow the given mathworld link, it literally says "Down arrow notation is an inverse of the Knuth up-arrow notation".

Comment: [Googology Wiki](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) defines the iterated logarithm as the number of iterations of the logarithm needed to get a result strictly $< 1$. (I don't know anything about this site - I just found it by searching.)

Comment: Wikipedia define the iterated logarithm as the number of iterations to get a result $\le 1$. Apparently there is not one fully agreed-upon definition.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair A couple of papers of mine are mentioned on the Googology Wiki page "Tetration", and (IMHO) it is a good source. Anyway, my first thought about finding an inverse notation for the well-known Knuth up-arrow notation is that tetration has two different inverse operators (i.e., Super Square-Root and Slog, as far as I know, where Super Square-Root is the inverse of Hyper-4 with respect to the base). Now, if we disregard the inverse operator with respect to the tetration base, I would take the Googology definition as the most reliable one on this topic (just my two cents).

Comment: @Marco - Thank you. I didn't mean to disparage Googology. I just didn't know anything about it, and am not knowledgable enough to make a judgment myself.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Of course, you are welcome!